# How to factorize a number in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am trying to build a function to factorize a number. in this example I used the number 95 and a list of prime numbers. The result should be (5, 19). What am I doing wrong?

```
function factorize(number, primes)
    global factor = Int64[]
    for i in primes
        while number % primes[i] == 0
            push!(factor, primes[i])
            number = number ÷ primes[i]
        end
        if number ÷ primes[i] != 1
            break
        end
    end
    return factor
end

number = 95
primes = (2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23, 27, 31)
answer = factorize(number, primes)
println(answer)
```

Comment: I'm quite sure this isn't the answer you're looking for, but you could use [Primes.jl](https://github.com/JuliaMath/Primes.jl) by running `import Pkg; Pkg.add("Primes");` and then `using Primes`,  `factor(95)`

Comment: You're right. I don't want to use a package. I'm only following `Project Euler`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fixed function:

```
function factorize(number, primes)
    factor = Int64[]
    for p in primes
        while number % p == 0
            push!(factor, p)
            number = number ÷ p
        end
        if number == 1
            break
        end
    end
    if number > 1
        @warn "factorization failed, not enough primes passed; printing only factors found in primes vector"
    end
    return factor
end
```

Changes:

- you do not need `global` qualifier
- writing `p in primes` returns you the elements of `primes` not the index into `primes`
- the termination condition should be `number == 1`
- error handling if `primes` vector does not contain all primes that are required

Note that you can compare your results with function `factor` from Primes.jl package (but I guess you wanted this code as an algorithmic problem).

Comment: Yes, this was an algorithmic problem taken from `Project Euler`. I do not see any `global` qualifier in your code.

Comment: Because I removed it. It was in your code in line `global factor = Int64[]`.

Comment: OK, I understand. You meant you do NOT need `global` qualifier.

Comment: Yes, I fixed it in the answer :).